# Gatsby's plugin generated sitemap.xml returning 404 error

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, gatsby, sitemap, netlify

### Explanation

I'm using [gatsby-plugin-sitemap](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/) to generate `sitemap.xml` for a Gatsby site, but, for some reason that I can't find, it's returning 404 error whenever I try to access it.

### Example

I created [this testing repo](https://github.com/machadoluiz/sitemap-test1) and hosted on Netlify (as the original is), to help debugging.

URL: https://sitemap-test1.netlify.app/

sitemap.xml: https://sitemap-test1.netlify.app/sitemap.xml (returning 404)

Thanks in advance,

Luiz.

Comment: [Maybe this might help you](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31095#issuecomment-829108655).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known bug of the library, as you can see in the following GitHub threads:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31167
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31095

That said, you can downgrade to version `3.30` which seems to be bug-free and be aware of using `options.excludes` instead of `options.exclude` (trailing "s") if you are excluding some pages.

Otherwise (and in the meantime) you can set the output path to `/` as a temporary workaround:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sitemap",
      options: {
        output: "/",
        query: `
        {
          allSitePage {
            nodes {
              path
            }
          }
          allWpContentNode(filter: {nodeType: {in: ["Post", "Page"]}}) {
            nodes {
              ... on WpPost {
                uri
                modifiedGmt
              }
              ... on WpPage {
                uri
                modifiedGmt
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
        resolveSiteUrl: () => siteUrl,
        resolvePages: ({
          allSitePage: { nodes: allPages },
          allWpContentNode: { nodes: allWpNodes },
        }) => {
          const wpNodeMap = allWpNodes.reduce((acc, node) => {
            const { uri } = node
            acc[uri] = node

            return acc
          }, {})

          return allPages.map(page => {
            return { ...page, ...wpNodeMap[page.path] }
          })
        },
        serialize: ({ path, modifiedGmt }) => {
          return {
            url: path,
            lastmod: modifiedGmt,
          }
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ferran! I'll stick with the downgrade until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "gatsby-plugin-sitemap" version, you might get a different sitemap path. Check out the HTML headers in your generated files and search for the sitemap path there.